# How do I go back after click on an internal bookmark in a Google Doc?

Tags: google-drive

After I click on an internal bookmark in a Google Doc, how do I get back to my previous position? The browser back button doesn't work for this.

Comment: Have you tried the "back" button in your browser?

Comment: yes, and not work.

Comment: Perhaps you can share the google docs with us?

Comment: You can create any doc and test it, that just take 1min if you know create bookmarks and links to them. Thanks.

Comment: Workaround: Ctrl+Click the link. It will open in another window, and after you close it, you get back to your original window with cursor at original location.

Comment: And still in 2019 it's not there? What a stupidity..

Comment: @alexkovelsky I tried to do so But then tureened out if there's more then 1 copy of a doc edited at a time serious bugs/glitches appear (titles from links disappear/get reordered) ... Why GOOGLE couln't make it perfect?! (Ah probably answer's clear: $$ (( I mean that i's free of chanrge)

Comment: @Rules I didn't notice any bugs. But maybe it's better to only view, not edit same file in multiple tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to use the back button to easily get tot he previous position in a doc.

If you are trying to do something like jump from one spot to another and back, what you can try is something like a `Back to top` link.

For example: if you have a table of contents at the top of a doc that jumps to headers below, you can insert a Table of Contents or set up bookmark links as usual.

Next, add a bookmark on the Table of Contents header itself.

Finally, next to any targeted headers in the doc, add the text "(back to top)" and link it to the Table of Contents bookmark. This will let users jump back to the original point.

Comment: Good method, but too tedious for my uses cases. My document have a lot of linked parts, and one bookmark can me reached from multiples links, so, in each bookmark I must put a 'back link' to each part of the document users could be using to reach that bookmark. In resume, your method no apply to my situation. Still I thanks you for let me know that not exist such 'go back' feature in google doc.

Comment: Bit of a necro-post, but this comes up high on the Google search results so I'll chime in.  If you create a "Top" bookmark at the top of your document, you can create a link to that bookmark in a footer (Insert > Footer).  That way it automatically gets re-created on every page, saving you the trouble of manually creating it.

Comment: Really not sure how this is at all useful.  When editing or reading a document, it's always useful to be able to navigate back to the previous view/edit location, whether it's after clicking an internal link or using the find words dialog.  This is a serious deficiency in Google docs.

Comment: @glenviewjeff   
Does MS Word have "go back" functionality?

Comment: @alexkovelsky it absolutely does.  Hit alt+ backspace.  I map my mouse's back button to this combination using AutoHotkey.

Comment: If the point of your link is just to return to the top, skip it and use `Control-Home`. Less clutter in your document and less time wasted building pointless links. You *can* use middle mouse button click to open the section in a new tab. Then you can just close the tab to return.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found 'another' hacky solution. Basically just before clicking on the 'link' make a dummy edit (like adding a 'space' or 'dot' etc) around some empty space in the neighborhood of the link. And then click the link. This should take you to the link location. After reading through the content, now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, and 'not only' will your dummy edit be undone (thanks to auto-save Google feature, you're changes will be rolled-back for sure), 'but also' you will get back to your link. Enough said, 'Google docs' must find a way for us to get back naturally though.

Comment: Good tip. It is crazy that Google have this that is a real bug in its Google Documents. Let's say that you have Appendixes in your long document where you reference to from various points of that self document, definitely it is a natural need to jump to reference and then jump back to the previous position ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

If you just "jumped" to a section and want to go back, you "unjump" by clicking on the "undo" arrow (that goes backwards and is next to the forward one).  It will undo just the jump, as that is the prior action to undo - it will not undo text or any previous moves if you only click it after you jumped.

Comment: That's not true. Navigation does not go onto the undo/redo stack, at least in 2021.

Comment: Navigation doesn't go onto the stack, but undo will take you back to the last change you made, however it will also undo that change.  This gives the possibility to use it by deliberately doing an unwanted change (as it ArunKumar's answer)  However that only works if you are editing the document, not just reading it.